# Twilio Paging Information

Tags: php, twilio

Im using the Twilio PHP Sdk.

```
$AccountSid = env('TWILIO_SID');
$AuthToken = env('TWILIO_TOKEN');
$this->twi = new TwilioClient($AccountSid, $AuthToken );
```

And Im retrieving call logs like so.

```
$calls = $this->twi->calls->read(["to" => "+".$number->number], 15);
```

This is fine, and is returning 15 records of the latest calls.
But how do I access paging information such as how many total records are available, and how many pages are available to view.  So that I can display some sort of pagination on my page??

I tried just accessing the Calls.json object, via CURL without using the SDK, like this...

```
$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/".$AccountSid."/Calls.json?PageSize=15";
```

And that gave me a nice JSON object, with some paging info such as next_page_uri and previous_page_uri.

```
[previous_page_uri] =>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC##########/Calls.json?PageSize=15&Page=0
[page_size] => 15
[start] => 0
[next_page_uri] => /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC##########/Calls.jsonPageSize=15&Page=1&PageToken=PACA27b63143f18c458f2abd35ef90753e5a
[page] => 0
```

But still, no totals such as total records, or total pages in the query???  So I cant display a nice bar of pagination at the bottom of my table, to show how many actual pages there are?
This seems dumb.

Is there no way to get this information?? Without actually storing the calls individually in my own database, so I can provide this manually?

Also.....one other question (assuming I cant retrieve that information)
I still want to be able to navigate from page to page, via the SDK instead of CURL requests. So....how do I pass the page number to the Twilio SDK?  Ive tried...

```
$calls = $this->twi->calls->read(["To" => "+".$number->number,"Page"=>22], 15);
```

But it still just returns the first page.  So how do I paginate these records via the SDK??

Comment: I found this https://www.twilio.com/blog/replacing-absolute-paging-and-related-properties  which shows that there used to be a numpages, and total provided by Twilio.  But they removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about total pages, but for pagination i have used TWILIO PHP SDK's function,

Here how it will work,

```
//this will fetch first 10 calls
$calls = $twilio->calls->page([], 10, \Twilio\Values::NONE, 0);

//then you just need to call 2 methods for next and previous page
$nextPageData = $calls->nextPage(); //this will return data of next page
$previousPageData = $calls->previousPage(); // this will return data of previous page

// to check if current page has valid data
if(!$nextPageData->valid()){
   //Invalid page
}
```

This is what i used for pagination on my project.